# Multiple monitors in XP: Not having to set their relative position every time

Tags: windows, windows-xp, multiple-monitors

I have an ASUS Eee netbook with Windows XP installed on it. I often connect an external monitor, and work with both monitors. This works well, except for one thing: Every time I connect the monitor and choose "LCD + CRT Extend" in the ASUS menu, I have to set the relative position of the monitors myself. They are by default side-by-side, while I want one to be above the other. Every time I connect the big monitor it shows up on the side instead of on top, and I have to go to "Display Properties" and set it to be on top!

Is there some way to make my configuration the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a different ASUS laptop, but for mine, there's an Intel graphics program thingy that sits in the system tray (I think by default: maybe needs to be configured from the control panel - it has its own applet, it's not under display), and that lets me create profiles which include position iirc. I've been using Linux for a couple of years now, so I can't quickly check.

**Edit:**
I found a laptop with this installed. *It does record the screen's position as part of the profile.* Go to Control Panel and look for **Intel(R) GMA Driver for Mobile**.

Comment: Works! I saved my settings as a theme and now I can apply it in two clicks: One right click on my desktop, then I click on my theme.

Comment: Cool! I remember I found it very useful under Win.

Answer (score 1):

Ultramon or Display Fusion would allow you to do this. It allows you to create profiles which you can set to default/save.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be an acceptable solution, but have you tried
[UltraMon?](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/overview/)
It's quite useful for multi-monitors, even if you don't use the external one constantly.

Hope that works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

The freeware [Display Changer](http://www.12noon.com/displaychanger.htm) is a command-line utility that can configure all the properties of a monitor, including its relative position to the primary monitor.

For example, to move a specified monitor currently positioned on the right of the primary to the left of it:

> dccmd.exe -monitor="Dell 2009W(Digital)" -left

As another example, to list all monitors:

> dccmd -listmonitors

You could write a script that creates the preferred monitor layout, and set it to run automatically after login in Start menu / Programs / Startup.